# How to get last object from array of object based on condition in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have some objects, that I am receiving one after another using `settimeout` function and then pushing every time into array to populate into a table. That is coming dynamically in my project but just for reference I am using `settimeout` and hard coding here.

Now my problem is, whenever I am receiving data using `settimeout`, I need to get last object by filtering with vehicle_number (if it contains same vehicle_number, I need to get last object of that vehicle_number) and need to populate/push into table again. Here is the code I have tried.

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let x of groupList">
<td>{{x.vehicle_number}}</td>
<td>{{x.status}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata1: any;
vehicle_number:any;
groupList:any = [];

constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
     /* First data */
    this.statusdata1 = {"vehicle_number":1,"status":"red"};
     this.groupList.push(this.statusdata1);
     console.log(this.groupList);

     /* second data */
    setTimeout (() => {
        this.statusdata1 = {"vehicle_number":1,"status":"green"};
         this.groupList.push(this.statusdata1);

         console.log(this.groupList);
      }, 5000);
   /* Third data */

      setTimeout (() => {
        this.statusdata1 = {"vehicle_number":2,"status":"yellow"};
         this.groupList.push(this.statusdata1);
         console.log(this.groupList);
      }, 10000);


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a quick function to update the value like the following

```js
private updateGroupList(statusData: any) {
  for (const key in this.groupList) {
    if (this.groupList[key].vehicle_number === statusData.vehicle_number) {
      this.groupList[key].status = statusData.status;
      return;
    }
  }
  this.groupList.push(statusData);
}
```

And you could replace all `this.groupList.push()` in the `ngOnInit()` with `this.updateGroupList(this.statusdata1)`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  /* First data */
  this.statusdata1 = {"vehicle_number":1,"status":"red"};
  this.updateGroupList(this.statusdata1);
  console.log(this.groupList);

  /* Second data */
  setTimeout (() => {
    this.statusdata1 = {"vehicle_number":1,"status":"green"};
    this.updateGroupList(this.statusdata1);
    console.log(this.groupList);
  }, 5000);

  /* Third data */
  setTimeout (() => {
    this.statusdata1 = {"vehicle_number":2,"status":"yellow"};
    this.updateGroupList(this.statusdata1);
    console.log(this.groupList);
  }, 10000);
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmxm8x)

Stackblitz GIF

[image: working gif]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this object is not populating {"vehicle_number":2,"status":"yellow"} , it should also check in same way and populate after first object...so on

Comment: It is populating in the stackblitz. As per the settimouts, you need to wait 10 seconds for it to happen.

Comment: I've posted a working gif capture of the stackblitz

Comment: [**Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)